# Turning off VSCode's auto-enclosing quotes?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't figure out how to get VSCode to *not* enclose the current selection in single- or double-quotes if I select some text and then type `'` or `"`. I've tried searching for a `'`-based key shortcut, and I’ve tried removing it as a keyboard shortcut with:

```json
    {
        "key": "'",
        "command": "-editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "textInputFocus"
    }
```

But that doesn’t seem to do anything.

I've also set the close-quote prefs to Never.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can delete the selected text before you press `'`.
2. The option is "editor.autoSurround"
   [image]
   or in the UI:
   [image]